# Correct way to use done() while testing asyc/await with mocha

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js

I am practicing basic unit test cases with `mocha` and a bit confused **HOW** and **WHEN** to use [done()](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha.reporters.xunit#done) handler.

1. **How to use `done()` ?**

Below is my sample code where I am not able to use `done`:

```
it('Testing insertDocumentWithIndex', async (done) => {
  try{
    var data = await db.insertDocumentWithIndex('inspections', {
      "inspectorId" : 1,
      "curStatus" : 1,
      "lastUpdatedTS" : 1535222623216,
      "entryTS" : 1535222623216,
      "venueTypeId" : 1,
      "location" : [
        45.5891279,
        -45.0446183
      ]
    })
    expect(data.result.n).to.equal(1);
    expect(data.result.ok).to.equal(1);
  }
  catch(e){
    logger.error(e);
    done(e);
  }
})
```

When I run, it fails and throws an error-

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
> "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

But `done` should be called in case of failure only(Please correct me If I am missing something, I am a beginner), which I have done in `catch` block and coming to the second point of returning a Promise, well that works fine. See below code

```
it('Testing insertDocumentWithIndex', async () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try{
      var data = await db.insertDocumentWithIndex('inspections', {
        "inspectorId" : 1,
        "curStatus" : 1,
        "lastUpdatedTS" : 1535222623216,
        "entryTS" : 1535222623216,
        "venueTypeId" : 1,
        "location" : [
          45.5891279,
          -45.0446183
        ]
      })
      expect(data.result.n).to.equal(1);
      expect(data.result.ok).to.equal(1);
      resolve()
    }
    catch(e){
      reject(e);
    }
  })
});
```

But this requires an additional Promise construction code which is antipattern. But it raises another question

2. **WHEN `done` should be used ?**

Any help or suggestion for a better approach for writing test cases with `mocha` will help.

Comment: Is logger.error really needed? It's expected that Mocha will report spec errors by itself.

Comment: Yes, from logs it seems `done` is enough to get error info and stacktrace. Hence `logger` can be removed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct way is to not use `done` with `async..await`. Mocha supports promises and is able to chain a promise that is returned from `it`, etc. functions. And `async` function is syntactic sugar for a function that always returns a promise:

```
it('Testing insertDocumentWithIndex', async () => {
    var data = await db.insertDocumentWithIndex('inspections', {
      "inspectorId" : 1,
      "curStatus" : 1,
      "lastUpdatedTS" : 1535222623216,
      "entryTS" : 1535222623216,
      "venueTypeId" : 1,
      "location" : [
        45.5891279,
        -45.0446183
      ]
    })
    expect(data.result.n).to.equal(1);
    expect(data.result.ok).to.equal(1);
})
```

`done` is needed only for testing asynchronous APIs than don't involve promises. Even then, converting to promises often results in cleaner control flow.

And this

```
it('Testing insertDocumentWithIndex', async () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  ...
```

is promise construction antipattern, which is even worse because of `async` promise constructor callback.

These concerns also apply to other JS testing frameworks with similar API, Jest and Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not caused by where you use `done` parameter, as @estus-flask told you, `done` is not used with async/await pattern. Your problem is due the promise is taking more than the default 2000ms timeout for the test function;  you have to increase that time. One way is using `--timeout 5000` (more or less) in the command line when you call mocha, but the recommended way is to set it into each `describe` function, or even into each `it` function like this:

```js
describe('Your description', function() {
  this.timeout(7000);
  // your tests
});
```

or

```js
describe('Your description', function() {
  it('Your test', async function())
    this.timeout(7000);
    // your tests with await
  });
  it('Another no-async test', function(done) {
    // your not-async test
    done();
  });
});
```

Remember to not use arrow functions when you use the `this` keyword:

```js
describe('Your description', () => {
  this.timeout(7000); // It will not work.
  // your tests
});
```