# Unit Testing using mocha, node

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm new to unit testing in the Node world and am struggling with this: I've setup a after cb to delete the records I've added during my tests, however I keep getting an error `Error: done() called multiple times` every time I delete the record on the db. Here's my code:

```
after((done) => {
    User.deleteOne({email: user_email}, function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
        done();
    });
});
```

If I do anything else (like just console something within the `after` block, I get no error at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `async/await` style.

```
after(async () => {
   const deleteResult = await User.deleteOne({email: user_email});

   console.log(deleteResult);
});
```

With `async/await` you don't need to execute done, because mocha automatically handle promises.

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52449252/6066986) and [here](https://wietse.loves.engineering/testing-promises-with-mocha-90df8b7d2e35)