# Mocha complains about timeout with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, puppeteer

Here is a simple version of my test:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const { expect } = require('chai')

const options = {
    timeout: 15000
}

let browser, page;

// setup
before(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(options)
    page = await browser.newPage()
})

// teardown
after(async () => {
    await page.close()
    await browser.close()
})

// utility functions
const withText = (text, element = '*') => `//${element}[contains(., '${text}')]`

describe('tests', () => {
    it('login', async () => {
        let user = 'foobar'
        let pw = 'password1'
        await page.goto('http://localhost:3000', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
        await page.waitForXPath(withText('Sign In'))

        await page.type('#user', user, { delay: 50 })
        await page.type('#password', pw, { delay: 50 })
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' })
    })
})
```

When I run above code via `mocha --timeout 15000 test.js` (no real test yet, simply trying to see if the form gets filled), login test above throws the following error:

```
Error: Timeout of 15000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Afaik, mocha only needs `done()` call if the test is NOT async (another thread confirms this: [Correct way to use done() while testing asyc/await with mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449202/correct-way-to-use-done-while-testing-asyc-await-with-mocha)). But even with done, the above test throws timeout error. When testing with `headless: false`, even the setup and teardown functions themselves throw the same error. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Fixed, issue turned out to be that my `waitForXPath` selector was timing out because our browser compatibility checker was flagging puppeteer and serving an error instead of a sign-in form.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but try `networkidle2` not `networkidle0`

Comment: That wasn't it but I realized my real problem, the `waitForXPath` selector was failing my test because our internal bot detection script was loading an error message instead of a sign-in form, and the test was failing prior to my screenshot showing me that. Fixed the issue by specifying a user-agent string.